# PHP Carbon parse error: Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have to parse a time and subtract with another time but it returns error when time is more than 23hours.

I have two variables `$countWorkHours = 42:00:00`
and `$countStayDinner->lunch = 5` .

I'm using `carbon` and I'm doing this:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($countWorkHours)->subHours($countStayDinner->lunch)->format('H:i:s')
```

but returns me this error: `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (42:00:00) at position 0 (4)`

It just work if first date is less than 24 hours.
What is the problem? How can I solve that?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicates should send you in the right direction - you're going to have to do your own math on the hours/minutes/seconds here. `42:00:00` isn't a valid date/time string as there's no 42 o'clock in our times.

Comment: I think CarbonInterval/DateInterval might be what you need. The tricky part would be to convert your time string to a time period.